# Can't get RTPEngine to work with Kamailio and Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip, kamailio

I just can't get  rtpengine to work.  i have tried multiple configurations, but to no avail.  I would appreciate any help/advice I can get.  Note that calls work good if rtpengine is disabled.

Here is my setup =>

Public IP: 20.20.20.20
Private IP 10.10.10.10

flow =>
webrtc client <-> kamailio+rtpengine <-> asterisk <-> kamailio <-> legacy sip phone

rtpenngine startup (I have tired a few different startups) =>
rtpengine --interface=int/10.10.10.10 --interface=ext/10.10.10.10!20.20.20.20 --listen-ng=127.0.0.1:12221 --pidfile=/var/run/rtpengine --dtls-passive -f -m 10000 -M 20000 -E

kamailio =>
Invites: rtpengine_manage("trust-address replace-origin replace-session-connection direction=ext direction=int ICE=remove RTP/AVP");
Reply's: rtpengine_manage("trust-address replace-origin replace-session-connection ICE=force RTP/SAVPF");

I have tried direction ext ext; and many other combinations, each producing it's own incorrect behavior.

I would really appreciate any help!

Thank you,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

Try using the actual interface name in your configuration and listen on the loopback and the internal IP.

```
--interface=eth1/10.10.10.10!20.20.20.20
--listen_ng=127.0.0.1:12221
--listen_ng=10.10.10.10:12221

Configure Kamailio to contact rtpengine on 10.10.10.10:12221.
```

Rtpengine modified packets can exceed the UDP size limit, therefore if you are using UDP for signaling anywhere, check if these packets are being fragmented as a result. If that is the case, then the only real solution is to use TCP for all legs.